# throw assignment operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

C++

How do I throw an error when someone calls the assignment operator?

I have a base class that uses a factory method instead of a constructor.  The factory methods reads a file and calls the derived class constructor based on the file contents.

```
Base *a::create(file1);
Base *b::create(file2);
```

I want to throw an error if someone calls the assignment operator.

```
*a = *b; // filetype contents don't match
```

At this moment when the above is executed, my *a's contents are overwritten by *b. I'm assuming its calling the implicit assignment operator, which is what I don't want to happen.

When I declare the assignment operator private. I get the following errors when I run it in a separate test file.

```
test.cc:34:13: fatal error: 'operator=' is a private member of 'Test'
    *aa = *ad;
    ~~~ ^ ~~~
./Base.h:14:16: note: declared private here
    Base& operator=(const Base &rhs);
           ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I would like it to rather throw an error instead of what is shown above.   Like "you can't do this" or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried making it public and using `throw`?

Comment: `I would like it to rather throw an error instead of what is shown above. Like "you can't do this" or something.` Isn't this exactly what you're getting right now? The compiler is telling you `You can't do this`. Alternatively you can `= delete` the function, the error would be different, the result would be the same.

Comment: I'm told it has to display an error message and the assignment operator can't be public.

Comment: It _does_ display an error message. What is your problem?

Comment: I was docked points for not throwing an error.  It displayed what is shown above.  I'm supposed to throw an error and the method can't be public.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "throw an error". A "fatal error" is compiler-speak for "the compiler detects this code as invalid, so you can't do that".  If you want the code to compile, but throw an exception at run time, then implement `operator=()` so it throws an exception. However, in general terms, it is better to diagnose errors as early as possible - a failed compilation (which the developer must fix in order to build the program) is better than a run time error (user must report the problem to the developer, who then must then find the cause of an unspecific problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile time errors are better than runtime ones (because they prevent the developer from thinking their code might work when it actually has no chance).  The right thing to do is declare the unusable operators and constructors as private or protected, so that they cannot be used except by `friend`s (e.g. factories).

Comment: Can you not delete the assignment operator(s) in modern C++?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sure, you can `= delete` the operators, in which case it doesn't matter if they're `public` or not.  Good point, assuming the functions aren't needed by a factory.